# Github Pages not using index.html

Tags: github-pages

I have a gh-pages branch in my repository.  My gh-pages branch and master branch are in an identical state.  Both have `index.html` included in them.  The settings page for my repository says `Your site is published at https://[me].github.io/[appName]/`.  When I visit that URL, I receive a 404 error.  When I visit `https://[me].github.io/[appName]/index.html` (with the specific asset `index.html` specified explicity) then it works, meaning the expected assets are located where expected, and function correctly.  How can I get GH Pages to pick up my index.html file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem resolved with a subsequent code change and push to origin.  I don't know why, but after performing a bug fix and pushing the code via `git push origin gh-pages` everything showed up on all machines in all regions in all browsers that were previously not working.

Comment: I was sceptical but I tried to do a "fake" commit (adding spaces) and redeploying and it worked! Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have declared a proper `!DOCTYPE` in your index file.
2. If you had just added the file, then give it some time and let github detect the file. `https://[me].github.io/[appName]/` should work after a while.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is set correctly at the top of the file.  How much time is "a while"?

Comment: DNS usually resolves within 24hours or less. What do you get on the browser console when opening the link without the index.html filepath?

Comment: It started working after I pushed a subsequent code change so I can't check the browser.  It was suggested by a coworker that sometimes a gh-pages deploy fails silently and will not retry until you push another code change.  This seems to have worked, though it isn't a satisfying way of "fixing" the problem if there was no problem with the code itself.

Comment: Oh ok. Interesting. You should open a new issue thread on GitHub with regards to this. Really weird.